# Ordered data before update in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, temp-tables

I have a temp table inside a stored procedure.

What I am doing is fetching data from different table and inserting it into temp table using

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable
  SELECT * FROM t1
  INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

After inserting, I need to update one column. Before updating the temp table I want to order the temp table data by another column.

How can I apply `ORDER By` clause before update clause on temp table?

Comment: How is the `ORDER BY` clause should affect your `UPDATE` clause?? Because the `ORDER BY` clause is just a presentation order, but the order of the way the rows are stored is insignificant. The `ORDER BY` clause shouldn't affect the `UPDATE` clause.

Comment: A table never has an order - you cannot order a table per se. Only **result sets** (results from a `SELECT`) have order - if you specify an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: My data represent the size of one item, so i need to arrange or order data, let say 0 to 100, then update another column. If data is not ordered then when i update data at that time updated value would be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your temporary table has an IDENTITY field.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable 
(
  ID int identity(1,1) primary key
  ...
)
```

Put an order by on your initial insertion:-

```
INSERT INTO 
  #TempTable
SELECT * FROM t1
INNER JOIN 
  t2 
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
ORDER BY [Your Field]
```

**Rationale:-**
Some may argue that putting the identity field in is unnecessary, or indeed that the order of the rows in the temp table is unimportant.  I'd disagree.

First, having an ID field allows you to do joins like :-

```
SELECT 
   t1.*, t2.SpecificThing
FROM
   #TempTable t1
INNER JOIN
   #TempTable t2
ON  t1.ID = ( t2.ID + 1)
```

Which can be handy for any running total / cumulation tricks.

As for ordering not being important in a temp table, I'd disagree - at least on **SQL Server**. The UPDATE statement on SQL Server updates rows *in order*.  If it didn't, this fascinating (and very speedy) running total trick would never work.

```
CREATE TABLE #CustomerInfo 
(
   ID int identity(1,1) primary key,
   CustomerId int,
   SaleValue money,
   RunningTotal money
)

-- Assume customer is populated

DECLARE @RunningTotal decimal(18,4)
DECLARE @CustomerId INT

SELECT @CustomerId = CustomerId FROM #CustomerInfo WHERE Id = 1
SET @RunningTotal = 0

-- This only works in SQL Server because under the hood, the engine is updating
-- iteratively in order.
-- 
-- Starts at row 0, then row 1 - with each row the value of @RunningTotal
-- is reassigned.
UPDATE #CustomerInfo
SET 
   @RunningTotal = 
   RunningTotal = 
   CASE WHEN 
      -- Are we still looking at the same customer?
      @CustomerId = CustomerId 
   THEN 
     -- Yes. Add sale value to @RunningTotal
     @RunningTotal + SaleValue
   ELSE
     -- No, reset @RunningTotal to SaleValue of this row
     SaleValue
   END 
   ,@CustomerId = CustomerId
 FROM #CustomerInfo
```

Comment: If i use below query
 INSERT INTO  #TempTable
SELECT * FROM t1
INNER JOIN   t2 
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
ORDER BY [Your Field]
I don't thing ORDER BY Clause work becoz ORDER BY works correctly on select statement not on views, derived table, sub queries and so on. If we will use order by clause this way then there is not guaranty  that ORDER BY works.

Comment: You're wrong.  Try it.  Very easy to verify.  Your ID fields should count up in the order of the column you're ordering on.